# Install PHP interpreter on LAMP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I've installed lamp and my `php -v` is 7.1.15. i created a form and when i request to a .php file, it says:

> php-cgi not found: Please ensure that configured PHP Interpreter built as CGI program (--enable-fastcgi was specified)

but I've specified the php.ini file from `etc/php/7.1/cli`.
and in setting/languages & Frameworks/php/cli interpreter it says php version not installed & debugger not installed.

Comment: try with /usr/bin/php

Comment: Apache doesn’t use the cli version

Comment: You are trying to use PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server .. which requires FastCGI compatible local PHP installed. If you are using LAMP stack -- just use actual Apache to serve your pages and not built-in web server.